# way to calculate crc for msp430f5438a using inbuilt function

Tags: crc, msp430

i have gone through CCITT and TI's Document regarding msp430. Is it possible to calculate CRC for MSP430F5438A using any in built function? Or do i have to calculate CRC for each data taken.

Comment: Have you seen this thread? http://e2e.ti.com/support/microcontrollers/msp430/f/166/t/19030.aspx

Answer (score 0):

A software implementation can be used in place of using the hardware peripheral on the MSP430F5438A. It can be implemented as follows:

```
unsigned short crc16(volatile unsigned char *sbuf,unsigned char len){
    unsigned short crc=0xFFFF;

    while(len){
        crc=(unsigned char)(crc >> 8) | (crc << 8);
        crc^=(unsigned char) *sbuf;
        crc^=(unsigned char)(crc & 0xff) >> 4;
        crc^=(crc << 8) << 4;
        crc^=((crc & 0xff) << 4) << 1;
        len--;
        sbuf++;
    }
    return crc;
}//crc16()
```

*Code courtesy of Jens-Michael Gross @ e2e.ti.com (http://e2e.ti.com/support/microcontrollers/msp430/f/166/t/19030.aspx)*